# Nagios, my own custom plugin doesnt work

Tags: bash, nagios

I'm trying to add my own custom check to nagios.
I have successfully created a bash script, that is executable from nagios user.
The problem is that this script works fine from linux command line, but it's return the unknown status if runned by nagios ( returned in web gui ).

```
#!/bin/sh

while getopts ":q:c:w:h:u:p" optname
do
    case "$optname" in  "q")    query=$OPTARG
                    ;;
                "c")    CIRT=$OPTARG
                    ;;
                "w")    WARN=$OPTARG
                    ;;
                "u")    user=$OPTARG
                    ;;
                "p")    pswd=$OPTARG
                    ;;
                "h")    echo "Useage: check_SQLplus_query -u user -p password -w warning value -c cirtical value"
                    exit
                    ;;
                "?")    echo "Unknown option $OPTARG"
                    exit
                    ;;
                ":")    echo "No argument value for option $OPTARG"
                    exit
                    ;;
                *)  # Should not occur
                    echo "Unknown error while processing options"
                    exit
                    ;;
    esac
done
RETVAL=`sqlplus -s  USER/PASSWORD@HOST:1521/DBNAME<<EOF
SET PAGESIZE 0 FEEDBACK OFF VERIFY OFF HEADING OFF ECHO OFF
$query;
EXIT;
EOF`
if [ "$RETVAL" -le "$CIRT" ]
then
    echo "OK - $RETVAL"
    exit 0
elif [ "$RETVAL" -gt "$CIRT" ] && [ "$RETVAL" -le "$WARN" ]
then
    echo "WARNING - $RETVAL"
    exit 1
elif [ "$RETVAL" -gt "$WARN" ]
then
    echo "CRITICAL - $RETVAL"
    exit 2
else
echo "UNKNOWN - $RETVAL"
exit 3
fi
```

Actually the user, password are "coded" inside script, even if I've already set the getopt to make this script more flexible.

The idea is simple, use sqlplus to get a simple query that return only a number ( like the number of the row like my case ).

Bash line to start the script:

```
/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_SQLplus_queryPrimavera.sh   -q "select count(*) from ADMUSER_PM.REFRDEL" -w 6000000 -c 8000000
```

Comment: for debugging, try `#!/bin/sh -x` as top line, I suspect it's something about your handling of RETVAL, maybe you mean the return code instead of the output (you are catching the output in RETVAL) - the returncode would be get after the SQLPLUS by `RETVAL=$?`

Comment: Since running from command line is ok, from which user do you run the shell script? Is it **nagios** user? If not try running it like `sudo -u nagios sh -c '/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_SQLplus_queryPrimavera.sh -q "select count(*) from ADMUSER_PM.REFRDEL" -w 6000000 -c 8000000'`

Comment: @Kadir , It's seams there is no problem of file permission, the user that I'm currently using via SSH is the same that nagios use to launch the script. 
Also, one important things that I've omitted before, the nagios GUI return  unknown status, reporting `UNKNOWN - `. IT's seams that the nagios run my script but maybe there "nothings" inside the RETVAL.

Now I put the full path of sqlplus in my script, but nothings change, It's seams that nagios when launch the check doesn't execute sqlplus

Comment: shouldn't that `sqlplus -s  USER/PASSWORD@HOST:1521/DBNAME<<EOF` read `sqlplus -s  ${user}/${password}@${HOST}:1521/DBNAME<<EOF` to make use of some variables?

Comment: Finally I make this plugin works ( so if someone need to use or just get ideas from that can use it! )
The problem was a system variable that is not "visible" running the plugin from nagios. In first instance I've excluded this case because the plugin works if launched from shell terminal (SSH) and not from nagios even if I use the same user.

You can "solve" setting the correct  $LD_LIBRARY_PATH inside the script or configure your system to use the correct one.